# typcasting a character array to a const char *

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have a character arraym
char Input[200];

input as of now has the string "abc.txt".

I have a method that strictly needs a const char *, how can I convert my input array into a const char *.

I tried casting it, and passing it, but upon using GDB, I feel like since the remaining 192 slots in input are filled with garbage(or are empty)its not being accepted by the function. When I pass the string literal "a.txt" to the function it works. so at this point I would like to extract the filled up elements from input array and convert it to a const char *.

I am taking input as a filename from a user, so I used a char array to store the input.

```
   int main()
    {
    char *name;

    char input[1024];
    strcpy(input, argv[1]);

    name = input;

    sys_open(input, "O_RDWR", 00700);


    }
```

Comment: Like I said in a comment on my answer, the second argument to `open` (or for that matter `sys_open` (which you should not call directly)) is **not** a string.

Comment: const char * filename, int flags, int mode. Those are the 3 parameters

Comment: Yes, so why are you passing the second argument as a string?

Comment: with or without that, it still works. I just did a test and created a char[] array, and it worked. But when I take input, it does not work. So I've concluded that this code over here is what is messing things up, what could it possibly be doing to it? when I do a printf, I see the string I need. Here is how I take input:  write(1, "input name: ", 12);
   sz = read(0, input, 1024);
   write(1, input, sz);  immediately once input is taken, I do a printf, and its exactly what it should be, i.e what the user provided. Keep in mind I cant use scanf, so thats my only option. What can the problem be?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please give me a hand here.

Comment: `open(input, O_RDWR, 00700); /* <--- note no quotes around O_RDWR */` You should have gotten compiler warnings about that!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Okay, but my original problem still exists. When I take input, I just debugged and provided that the user passed abc.txt, at position 7 there is a \n and at position 8 there is a \0, maybe because of that \n its not finding the file anymore? Please help me

Comment: If you use e.g. `fgets` then it leaves the newline still in the string. Use e.g. `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';` to remove the last character (the newline).

Comment: strlen is libc, and I can not use libc. How would I do without strlen?

Comment: Make your own? It simple, just loop and count until you get a `'\0'` and then return the counter.

Comment: That did not resolve it. I don't know what I am doing wrong with taking input using read and write.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that is what I did, and it still didn't work. if I pass a char array, its good. If I pass a char array who got input using read and write system calls, then it is not good.

Comment: Please show _complete_ code! You keep changing your story all the time.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg write(1, "input name: ", 12); sz = read(0, input, 1024); write(1, input, sz)  Using that code, when the user passes for example, sample.txt the length of sample.txt is returned as 20, that means there is about 9-10 extra characters. That imo is the problem

Comment: I fixed it. It was exactly what I thought it was. GDB FTW

Comment: And could you please elaborate on that, maybe put it in an answer even?

Comment: You are posting the same bogus code, in yet another question? Why is that? All that this proves is that you didn't read up before asking your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to pass it directly. A char[] can be cast to a const char *, but not vice versa.

The reason that you see all of the garbage in gdb is because arrays are not pre-initialized to contain anything, so you're just seeing whatever garbage was in there before. As long as your string is null-terminated, it should be fine.

Comment: if I have a string copied to it, do I need to allocate memory for the char prior to casting it, cause its not working for me, despite knowing that there is some text in the char. I feel that the space it has allocated is of 200, but sometimes a user can pass just 5 chars and the remaining 194 is empty therefore the function is not parsing it properly

Answer (score 2):

Arrays naturally decays to pointers so that's not a problem.

The problem with the "garbage" is because that's what in the memory where the array is located. The important thing to look after is that the string is terminated by the `'\0'` character.

So the string `"abc.txt"` looks like this

```
'a', 'b', 'c', '.', 't', 'x', 't', '\0'
```

What comes after this doesn't matter as all string functions stop at the `'\0'`.

If you are using the array containing the string, it's important to use `strlen` to get the length, and not `sizeof`, since the `sizeof` operator give the length of the whole array and not the contained string.

Comment: if I have an array of 200, and using the write system call, a user passes abc.txt, can I pass that to the sys_open as a const char* parameter. That is what I am doing and its not working. my logic is correct cause in that same function when I pass "abc.txt" as a literal, it works.

Comment: @user1888502 Maybe you should show _how_ you use this array? It seems likely you are using `sizeof` to give the length to the `write` call when you should be using `strlen`.

Comment: I am simply passing it as open(input, "O_RDWR", 00700);
where input is a char[200], that has abc.txt stored in it from the user, a printf with %s verifies it for me. But it does not work.

Comment: @user1888502 Of course it doesn't work, the `O_RDWR` flag is a _flag_ (i.e. an integer) not a _string_! You should have gotten compiler warnings about that! Please read the manual page for `open` more carefully.

Comment: sorry, I meant read. My open works, I apologize I meant read; as in sys_read, whose paramater is const char*, when I pass abc.txt, I get what I want. when the user passes abc.txt to my char array, I know I have it(despite having allocation 200 for the array)when I pass my array to read function, instead of the literal "abc.txt", it does not work.

Comment: @user1888502 Then please edit your question to show the actual code you have problem with, it's very hard to figure out what you're doing without seeing the actual code. Maybe create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: sorry, I meant read. My open works, I apologize I meant read; as in sys_read, whose paramater is const char*, when I pass abc.txt, I get what I want. when the user passes abc.txt to my char array, I know I have it(despite having allocation 200 for the array)when I pass my array to read function, instead of the literal "abc.txt", it does not work. – user1888502 1 min ago edit

Comment: I added code can you look at it now