# C - Unable to retrieve const char* value

Tags: c, pointers, char

In summary

```
void someVoid(const char* value_){
    const char* value = "SomeValues"; //This is summary for function that retrieves const char* values
    value_ = value;
}

int main(){
    const char* retrievedValue;
    someVoid(retrievedValue);
    
    //retrievedValue -> empty
}
```

Retrieved value after calling function, stays same as previously initialized

I can't change variable const char* to char* because I'm using function from additional library that retrieves const char* values

```
void someVoid(char* value_){
    const char* value = "SomeValues";
    value_ = (char*)value;
}

int main(){
    char retrievedValue;
    someVoid(retrievedValue);
    
    //retrievedValue -> empty
}
```

I tried casting (char*), it didn't work, retrievedValue is still empty

Comment: The question is about C. Why has it been closed as a duplicate of the C++ question?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you can't change the function signature. `void someVoid(const char* value_)`

Comment: Your pointer is passed by value (or copy).  The caller's parameter will not be modified by your code.

Comment: Solution was combination of 3 posts- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263493/modify-const-char-in-c
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785442/typcasting-a-character-array-to-a-const-char
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989892/converting-a-const-char-to-an-array